# matplotlib: no interactive window shown

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
>>> from pylab import *
>>> plot(1)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x2a9f9ce550>]
>>> show()
```

Nothing happens. No error message. No interactive window.

Someone know what's the problem could be?

The OS is RH4 and DISPLAY is set properly. Other GUI application can work fine.

Comment: which mpl version are you using ???

Comment: I downloaded the latest version. It's 1.1.0

Comment: maybe you mpl backend is not properly set ? I have no clue what this could be. Do other mpl codes work?

Comment: Other functionalities work fine. For example, I can successfully create PNG graphes.

Comment: so why do you need an empty plot to appear ? does figure() work ?

Comment: RH4 ? Is it python 2.4 ?. Is the last mpl version fully compatible with your python ?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you run that same example code as a python file (instead of typing it into the interpreter)?

Answer (score 0):

Oz123 is right, this can be caused by the wrong backend being set "svg","ps", and "cairo", for example, don't seem to support `show()` see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8864930/997378) for examples of how to change it, get "GTKcairo" working if it's not, or change the default