# barh produces wonky spacing between bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I've been generating bar charts that look like this:

[image]

Notice that the vertical spacing on the labels is uneven for some reason; I'm not sure if this has to do with how I have assigned the ticks or whatever mechanism is actually placing the text. Relevant code:

```
height_factor = 40.0
ind = np.linspace(0,len(sorted_totals)*height_factor,num=len(sorted_totals))
width = 0.25
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15.5, 8.75),dpi=300)
p1 = plt.barh(ind,map(int,sorted_composite[:,0]),color='blue',align='center',height=height_factor)
p1 = plt.barh(ind,map(int,sorted_composite[:,2]),color=(0.75,0.1,0.1),align='center',height=height_factor)
plt.ylabel('# of Picks (blue) + # of Bans (red)')
plt.yticks(ind, sorted_totals[:,0])
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.05, left=0.14,right=0.95,top=0.95)
plt.ylim([ind.min() - height_factor, ind.max() + height_factor])
```

My data is stored in sorted_composite and ind are the values I'm using to place the bars (the ytick locations). I'm using linspace to produce evenly spaced bars and this only kind of works and I'm not sure exactly why.

Comment: I was thinking that your problem may be related to having all those bars rather crammed, but I've been trying your code from 5 to ~50 bars and no problem here.

Comment: Yeah I have a feeling it's a pixel placement rounding issue.. ie if you have an image 8 pixels tall and want to draw a line through the center do you draw it along pixel row 4 or pixel row 5; either way looks bad

Comment: On a side note I get bad results even with a trivial test case:

`from numpy import *`
    from pylab import *
    data = zeros(50)+10
    ind = arange(10)
    barh(ind,data)
    show()`
Looks pretty bad

Comment: Version of matplotlib? Maybe you're hitting a but :?

Comment: Sorry yes that was a typo.. this is sample output from `bar(arange(50),zeros(50)+1)`: http://i.imgur.com/wqNrs.png  It almost never does a good job spacing them. As for versions: python-2.7.2 (32 on windows), mpl-1.1.0, numpy-1.6.1

Comment: I have somewhat resolved this issue although the solution is not so pretty, I am going to write a how-to on producing pixel-accurate bar charts and post it here for any interested parties.. might need a day to finish this

Answer (score 2):

like user1127062 suggests, it might be that your code is just fine.

If you don't need the plot to be interactive, save it as an svg

If you run:

```
data = numpy.random.randn(10000)
pylab.hist(data,300)
pylab.savefig(fileName+'.svg',format='svg')
```

you'll see the pixel aliasing (in the bar widths) in the figure window, but it's gone in the svg file.

The "cairo" backend seems to do the best job of saving png files, if svg's aren't compatible with what you're doing. They look as good as a screenshot of the svg.

You can switch the backend by running.

```
import matplotlib
# you have to change the backend before importing pylab
matplotlib.use('cairo') 
import pylab
```

raw "cairo" doesn't support `show()`, so you can't use it in interactive mode, or to show a plot directly from a program.

The "GTKCairo" backend has the best of both worlds but isn't enabled in the default installation (at least not in the one I got with `sudo apt-get install matplotlib`)

If you're using Ubuntu I think all you need to do to get it working is to install gtk, and recompile matplotlib:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core python-gtk2-dev
git clone git://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git
cd matplotlib
sudo python setup.py install
```

You can check which backend is active with:

```
matplotlib.get_backend()
```

You can automatically load your favorite backend by hunting down your `matplotlibrc` file, I found mine in:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc
```